# glmnet: which is the reference category or class in multinomial regression?

Tags: classification, multinomial-distribution, logit, glmnet

Following post 
[Why {glmnet} can be calculated parameters for all category?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67558/why-glmnet-can-be-calculated-parameters-for-all-category)

I have 4 categories or classes or responses for y (thus multinomial): *cat1, cat2, cat3* and finally *no-cat*. I want my "**no category (no-cat)**" class to be the **reference category**. Can I specify this in glmnet ? After performing a cv.glmnet I get coefficients for all categories.

Note: I'm a new glmnet user.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/glmnet-how-to-make-sense-of-multinomial-parameterization

Comment: Thx, I'will check this post, seems like a goog glmnet test tutorial